# Display title series in tooltip

Tags: charts, dojo, tooltip

I need display in tooltip title series chart. I have many series in my chart.
I try this:

->add series to chart<-

```
addSeries("Title1", new dojox.charting.StoreSeries(store, {query: {}}, {x: "time", y: "tzewn", text: "Title1"})).
```

I get data from json file. But text: isn't in my store data.

->tooltip<-

```
 new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(chartT, "default" 
        ,{text: function(e) {
           var tooltiptext = e.y +", "+e.text;
           return tooltiptext;
            }
        }       
    );
```

but I get: (e.y) the correct value and undefined (e.text),

How I can display name series in tooltip?

Answer (score 1):

Your StoreSeries is defined to look for a property named "Title1" in each object that comes from the store and assign that value to "text".

If you want the name of the series in your tooltip text, then try using `e.run.name` in your tooltip text function:

```
new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(chartT, "default", {
    text: function(e) {
       return e.y.y + ", " + e.run.name;
    }
});
```